# Filter an Array that has another array inside it

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I am trying to filter an array

```
const array = [{
    city: "Fullerton",
    routes: ["Route 1", "Route 2"],
    state: "CA"
}, {
    city: "Long Beach",
    routes: ["Route 3", "Route 4"],
    state: "CA"
}, {
    city: "Huntington Beach",
    routes: "Route 1",
    state: "CA"
}];
```

By another array:

```
const routes = ["Route 1", "Route 3"];
```

But, I'm having trouble filtering the routes item of the original array as it has arrays and strings as its variable.  Is there a way to use the routes array and filter the original array regardless of variable type?

Also, I would like it so that if you select one of the routes it will filter the array even if the array element contains more routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want at least one route matching, you can combine `some` and `includes`:

```js
const routes = ["Route 1", "Route 3"];
const array = [{city: "Fullerton", routes: ["Route 1", "Route 2"], state: "CA"}, {city: "Long Beach", routes: ["Route 3", "Route 4"], state: "CA"}, {city: "Huntington Beach", routes: "Route 1", state: "CA"}];

const filteredArray = array.filter(a =>
  [].concat(a.routes).some(r => routes.includes(r))
)

console.log(filteredArray)
```

If you need exactly all routes matching, `includes` is enough:

```js
const routes = ["Route 1", "Route 3"];
const array = [{city: "Fullerton", routes: ["Route 1", "Route 2"], state: "CA"}, {city: "Long Beach", routes: ["Route 3", "Route 4"], state: "CA"}, {city: "Huntington Beach", routes: "Route 1", state: "CA"}];

const filteredArray = array.filter(a => routes.includes(a.routes))

console.log(filteredArray)
```

Comment: The third element in the array contains `routes` property which is not an array

Answer (score 1):

You could convert a string to an array and check if some of the items are in `routes`.

```js
var array = [{ city: "Fullerton", routes: ["Route 1", "Route 2"], state: "CA" }, { city: "Long Beach", routes: ["Route 3", "Route 4"], state: "CA" }, { city: "Huntington Beach", routes: "Route 1", state: "CA" }],
    routes = ["Route 1", "Route 3"],
    result = array.filter(o => [].concat(o.routes).some(s => routes.includes(s)));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Indeed, there is no element inside the array contains `routes` property which has value `["Route 1", "Route 3"]`

Answer (score 0):

You can `filter` your array if `every` element in `routes` corresponds to some element of `routes`:

```
const result = array.filter(f=> 
    Array.isArray(f.routes) ? f.routes.every(r => routes.includes(r)) : false);
```

An example:

```js
const array = [{
    city: "Fullerton",
    routes: ["Route 1", "Route 2"],
    state: "CA"
}, {
    city: "Long Beach",
    routes: ["Route 3", "Route 4"],
    state: "CA"
}, {
    city: "Huntington Beach",
    routes: "Route 1",
    state: "CA"
}, {
    city: "Huntington Beach 1",
    routes: ["Route 1", "Route 3"],
    state: "CA"
}
];

const routes = ["Route 1", "Route 3"];

const result = array.filter(f=> 
    Array.isArray(f.routes) ? f.routes.every(r => routes.includes(r)) : false);

console.log(result);
```